# is Javascript array.push method synchronous?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple javascript function but it is not as I have expected.

The following is the code:

```
    var startDate = new Date('2015-07-01 00:00 +0800');
    var endDate = new Date('2015-07-10 00:00 +0800');
    var arrayOfDates = [];

    if (endDate >= startDate) {
        while (startDate < endDate) {
            arrayOfDates.push(startDate);
            startDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        }
    }
```

While I am expecting the result of `arrayOfDates` to be `[2015-07-01, 2015-07-02, 2015-07-03.... , 2015-07-10']`. The results is instead `[2015-07-02, 2015-07-03.... , 2015-07-10']`

Why is that? Is it somehow the `var startDate` is updated before the variable is pushed to the array? if that's the case how can I make sure the code is running synchronously?

Comment: seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/pjso2t2w/

Comment: I get July 1 - July 9 inclusive. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7z65chkb/

Comment: That time format isn't understood by Firefox.

Comment: In my browser, `endDate >= startDate` yields false.

Comment: To answer the titular question, yes. See the answers for what your real problem is.

Comment: so some get July-1 to July-9, I get July 2 to July 10.. I start to see it's a timezone problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `setDate()`, that *changes* the date. All the setter functions on the Date prototype mutate the date instance.

You have to make a new date instance and then subsequently call the setter to change it.

```
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate().getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will do job for you and it wont change your date untill your current date is pushed:

```
var startDate = new Date('2015-07-01 00:00');
    var endDate = new Date('2015-07-10 00:00');
    var arrayOfDates = [];

    if (endDate >= startDate) {
        for(var dt = startDate; startDate < endDate; dt = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1))){
            console.log(startDate);
            arrayOfDates.push(startDate);
        }
    }
```

Here you have fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ggqzbn6h/

Comment: This will have exactly the same problem as the code in the OP.